# Can you create a database backed rails model without a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel, scenic

I have a complicated SQL query that aggregates columns using a `group_by`.

```rb
IndividualOrder.select(SUM(...) as amount, other_fields).group_by("organization.id")
```

The problem is: I get an ActiveRecord::Relation from `IndividualOrder`, which isn't really what the result is conceptually anymore. I'm not entirely sure how to cast it to a new method. If I use `arel` to handle it, I still usually would have to go `IndividualOrder.arel_table`, and it would still cast to whatever I select.

I just want to take the fields `[:amount, :organization, :other]` and be able to interact with them as I would a database backed model that had those values as a table.

So, it's not quite a tableless model (which usually aren't database backed), and it's not an actual model because it's a generated query.

Is this the use case for scenic? I'm stuck with having to navigate around 2 variables that exist within the query that I'm doing via `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: Make a database view, use the view to back the model. It will be read only, but will otherwise work as an Active Record model.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there hope this answer helps you, this should be a comment not a answer( not enough karma for doing that yet)

what you can do is to create a view in your database,

```
rails g migration my_new_view
```

ActiveRecord does not give us any methods to create views so you will have to do "manually" or you can use specific gems for doing those.

```
 class MyNewView < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]

  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        execute <<-SQL
          CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_new_view AS

            # your sql query here SELECT ....
            SQL
      end

      dir.down do
        execute <<-SQL
          DROP VIEW IF EXISTS public.my_new_view;
        SQL
      end
    end
  end

end
```

now you can refer in your model.

Beware view tables will not show in schema by default, for seing them you have to put in your application.rb:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

cheers.